# Get a column value that showed up more than 3 times in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, window-functions

I am trying to filter out and show all the item_number that showed up at least 3 times or more. Below is my SQL query that I am have written.

```
SELECT row_number() over(partition by i.item_number order by i.item_number) row_num 
    ,i.item_number 
    ,sto.location_id
    ,sto.actual_qty
    ,trn.source_location_id
    ,trn.tran_qty
FROM #items i
LEFT JOIN (select loc.location_wh, sto.item_number, sto.location_id, sto.actual_qty, sto.status from t_stored_item sto WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN t_location loc WITH (NOLOCK)
        on loc.location_id = sto.location_id 
        where loc.location_wh = '80'
        and loc.type = 'I') sto
ON sto.item_number = i.item_number 
LEFT JOIN (select t.item_number, t.source_location_id, sum(t.tran_qty) tran_qty from t_tran_log t WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE t.tran_type = '305'
        and convert(date, end_tran_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') = '2021-11-16'
        GROUP BY t.item_number, t.source_location_id) trn
on trn.item_number = i.item_number
and trn.source_location_id = sto.location_id
WHERE sto.location_id IS NOT NULL
```

The data looks like this

```
row_num item_number location_id actual_qty source_location_id tran_qty
1   1040370 AL-27-03-A  120 NULL    NULL
2   1040370 BH-16-04-A  96  NULL    NULL
1   1089630 BV-59-04-F  192 NULL    NULL
2   1089630 BW-35-05-D  96  NULL    NULL
3   1089630 BQ-28-04-A  576 NULL    NULL
1   1132345 BZ-32-07-C  804 NULL    NULL
2   1132345 AG-51-02-B  588 NULL    NULL
3   1132345 BX-28-08-C  60  NULL    NULL
4   1132345 AH-18-06-B  600 NULL    NULL
5   1132345 BX-14-04-C  108 NULL    NULL
```

Now I want to show all the item_numbers that showed up 3 times at least or more. As you can see, 1089630 showed up 3 times so these should show up in my next nesting query. I tried this but it showed up empty.

```
;with temp as (
SELECT row_number() over(partition by i.item_number order by i.item_number) row_num 
    ,i.item_number 
    ,sto.location_id
    ,sto.actual_qty
    ,trn.source_location_id
    ,trn.tran_qty
FROM #items i
LEFT JOIN (select loc.location_wh, sto.item_number, sto.location_id, sto.actual_qty, sto.status from t_stored_item sto WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN t_location loc WITH (NOLOCK)
        on loc.location_id = sto.location_id 
        where loc.location_wh = '80'
        and loc.type = 'I') sto
ON sto.item_number = i.item_number 
LEFT JOIN (select t.item_number, t.source_location_id, sum(t.tran_qty) tran_qty from t_tran_log t WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE t.tran_type = '305'
        and convert(date, end_tran_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') = '2021-11-16'
        GROUP BY t.item_number, t.source_location_id) trn
on trn.item_number = i.item_number
and trn.source_location_id = sto.location_id
WHERE sto.location_id IS NOT NULL
--ORDER BY item_number 
)

select row_num, item_number, location_id, actual_qty, source_location_id, tran_qty 
from temp 
GROUP BY row_num, item_number, location_id, actual_qty, source_location_id, tran_qty
having count(item_number) >= 3
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: count(*) over(partition by i.item_number)… instead of row_number()

Comment: OMG this was so simple and I can't believe I couldn't think. It gave me expected result. Thanks a bunch @lptr

Comment: . . .  . . . .

Comment: Slight detour but worth reading. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: Thanks Sean for your input. I have had the same issue with using NOLOCK but our DBA prefer us using it IDK for what reason.

Comment: Probably because your DBA doesn't understand the pitfalls of using that dreadful hint. I have worked in shops where it was enforced and it was painful.

Comment: I agree. Can you please vote this question? It will be helpful for others with the same issue.